# Хочу получить _ID(sqlite) по нажатие item,  а получаю position item Listview?

Tags: adapter, android, listview, java, sqlite

Хочу получить _ID(sqlite) по нажатие item,  а получаю position item Listview? В чем моя ошибка и как исправить? можете если не трудно пример скинуть... Если делать через SimpleCursorAdapter, он  работает, но зачеркивает как устаревший метод...

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

```
public final static String name = "CONS_ID";
EditText inputContent1;
Button buttonAdd, btnPhoto;
ImageView imageView;
public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
ListView listContent;
Bitmap galleryPic = null;

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
Cursor cursor;

static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvItemName;
AdsAdapter adapter;

public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

public FragmentTwo() {

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    inputContent1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.content1);
    buttonAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
    btnPhoto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);

    listContent = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(getActivity());
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
    // String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID_ADS,
    //
    // SQLiteAdapter.KEY_TEXT_ADS, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_PHOTO_ADS };
    //
    // int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.imageViewBlack };
    // cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row,

    // cursor, from, to);
    // Log.d("my", "cursorAdapter");

    // listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    adapter = new AdsAdapter(getActivity(), initData());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

    // listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);

    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
    btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

ArrayList<String> arrayList;

private List<AdsGetSet> initData() {

    mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
    List<AdsGetSet> list = new ArrayList<AdsGetSet>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int idColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int nameColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Text_ads");

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        do {

            list.add(new AdsGetSet(cursor.getInt(idColIndex), cursor
                    .getString(nameColIndex), cursor.getBlob(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Photo_ads"))));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else
        cursor.close();

    return list;
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

        String data1 = inputContent1.getText().toString();
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, image);
        updateList();
    }

};

private ListView.OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Log.d("my", "position " + position);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("my", "id " + id);
_________________________________________________________________
```

Адаптер
public class AdsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private List<AdsGetSet> list;
private LayoutInflater inflateLayoutInflater; // доступ к layout -м

public AdsAdapter(Activity activity, List<AdsGetSet> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.list = list;
    inflateLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d("my", "list.size()" + list.size());
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("my", "list.get(position)" + list.get(position));
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("my", "position" + position);
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d("my", " getView position" + position);
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflateLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_listview, parent,
                false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idtext1);
    textView.setText(getAdsGetSet(position).getAdsText().toString());

    Log.d("my", "getAdsGetSet         "
            + getAdsGetSet(position).getAdsText().toString());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.adsImageView1);
    Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getAdsGetSet(position)
            .getImg(), 0, getAdsGetSet(position).getImg().length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(b1);

    return view;
}

private AdsGetSet getAdsGetSet(int position) {
    return (AdsGetSet) getItem(position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас же `getItemId` возвращает `position`. верните в нем `getAdsGetSet(position).getId()`. где `getId()` вернет то, что вы передаете в конструктор `new AdsGetSet()` первым параметром.
ЗЫ надеюсь `mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();` у вас не `writableDatabase` возвращает?